# Those "set" methods in AtomicInteger

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomicinteger

I am aware that `compareAndSet()` in `AtomicInteger` is a core method that takes a clever approach to atomically update the current value of the integer primitive that `AtomicInteger` encapsulates. It does so only after it has ascertained that another thread has not updated it already, and gives up if it detects otherwise.

Also, I know, the methods in `AtomicInteger` labelled "atomic" by the Java API documentation internally invoke `compareAndSet()`.

Having expressed the indispensability of `compareAndSet()` in `AtomicInteger`, my questions are:

- 1. Why does `weakCompareAndSet()` exist in `AtomicInteger`? Why would I ever choose to use it while `compareAndSet()` is available for use? According to the Java API,

     > it may fail spuriously and does not provide ordering guarantees, so is only rarely an appropriate alternative to `compareAndSet`.
- 2. Surprisingly, there is a raw `set()` method in `AtomicInteger`, which is not even labelled atomic! What is it doing in a class like `AtomicInteger`?!

Comment: probably when one does not need the guarantee.

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html: *set has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a volatile variable.*

Comment: @JB Nizet: Thanks! It has got all in one place. I didn't know there was such a page.

Comment: It's linked to by the second sentence of the javadoc of AtomicInteger: * See the java.util.concurrent.atomic package specification for description of the properties of atomic variables*

Comment: Excellent! Right on!..